# How to use lmod with fish?

Tags: module, fish, lmod

While lmod support fish from version 7.4 onwards, I have to use servers with an older version. How can I make it work with fish? (Even if in limited capacity.)

Answer (score 0):

This solution let me run commands like `module load R`. It may fail in the general case.

Define a convenience function as follows:

```
function module                                                                     
    eval $LMOD_CMD bash $argv | lmod_bash_to_fish.py | source -
end
```

where `lmod_bash_to_fish.py` has the contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import sys

f = sys.stdin

while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:
        break

    match = re.match(r'^(\w+)="(.+)";\n$', line)
    if not match:
        raise RuntimeError("Unexpected line: {}".format(line))

    var, val = match.groups()

    line = f.readline()
    if line != "export {};\n".format(var):
        raise RuntimeError("Variable not immediately exported: {}".format(line))

    if var == 'PATH':
        val = " ".join('"{}"'.format(elem) for elem in val.split(':'))
        print("set -gx fish_user_paths {}".format(val))
        continue

    print("set -gx {} \"{}\"".format(var, val))
```